# Background Image Before and After p tag

Tags: css, background-image

I found a potential solution to my problem on stack overflow, but it does not seem to be working for me. I want an image to appear before and after p.choke, so on the top and the bottom. I am using the following CSS:

```
p.choke:before{
    content:" ";
    background-image:url(...);
    background-position:center top;
}

p.choke:after{
    content:" ";
    background-image:url(...);
    background-position:center bottom;
}

p.choke{
    background-image:url(...);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center top;
    width:75%;
    line-height:2em;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0 auto;
    color:#009245;
    padding:1em 0;
}
```

The image should be appearing on the top and bottom of my paragraph tag, right? I read about other people having this same problem and this is the syntax they used. Why is my image only appearing on the top?

http://dev.myfishermanscove.com/resort-services/hours-and-rates/

Comment: What elements in that page are you trying to apply this affect to?

Comment: I think you need to set a width and height for your pseudo element in order to let html to know the size of your image

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
p.choke:after{
    content:" ";
    background-image:url(...);
    background-position:center bottom;
}
```

I used...

```
p.choke:after{
    content:url(...);
    background-position:center bottom;
}
```

Seems to be working now. Still not sure why the other way did not work.